# BackTrack Linux not showing Desktop after installation

Tags: kali-linux

I was running back-track kali through ISO file. Till then it was all fine and showing all features like Desktop and other GUI which it provides.

After installing, it is showing only the CMD terminal and no GUI or other features.

While installing, I remembered it asked:

> During installation the system will ask whether you want to use network mirror or not

I chose yes. Is this the reason for this issue?

Comment: If your question is about Backtrack, tag Backtrack, and don't tag Kali.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the command `startx`. The default username is `root` and the password is `toor`. Can you specify if your using backtrack or kali, as they are two different releases, with kali being the newer one?

[Basic Usage of Backtrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/Basic_Usage)

Comment: startx :command not found. i am using kali.

Comment: @vivek, when I installed kali, it did most of the work for me. I don't have to use startx to login, when I boot up it takes me to I believe the gnome gui login.

Comment: You may want to try the kali forums for help http://forums.kali.org/

Comment: I installed it using Install Kali option under Applications when it was running from ISO file.
After that when installation completed it is showing only the cmd terminal. I am a complete newbie to linux, so no idea what is wrong.

Comment: @vivek, unfortunatley I'm no expert myself, but keep trying things and i'm sure you'll figure it out. Don't be afraid to make a mistake.

Comment: @vivek, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oC_-8o2ZJSg maybe try reinstalling while following that video.

Comment: Well I have reached till as far as startx command. But now it gives  error "Connection to X host lost"
Any Idea?

Comment: @vivek, as I said previously you shouldn't have to be messing with command line interface just to log into kali. When your pc starts up it should show grub. you would choose kali from grub and then kali would load, which takes you to a graphical login.

Comment: @vivek, make sure the hard-drive/partition you are trying to install to has at least 15GB free space

Comment: @vivek This is the answer to your question.  You said you are using Backtrack, not Kali.  Very similar distros, as Backtrack is no longer in active development, but if you are indeed using backtrack, @Skateguy's answer is the answer you are looking for.  Like he said, after installing Backtrack, you have to login as `root` with password `toor`, and then execute the command `startx` in order for the GUI to showup and display correctly.  Are you trying to do this over SSH or something? Because if you are doing this from the console, it should work just fine.